# Equivalent of the French expression "n'avoir rien à envier à personne"

Tags: выражения, французский

> Pourtant, en matière d'écart de langage, elle **n'a rien à envier à** **personne**.
>
> ≈ *When it comes to an (offensive/inappropriate) slip of the tongue, however, she **has nothing to feel envious about** **towards anyone**.* {sarcastically said}

- *Someone made an inappropriate remark, but she’s had more than her fair share of slip-of-the-tongue moments herself. So when it comes to slips of the tongue, she **has nothing to feel envious about** towards anyone, as she is **every bit as good/bad as** others in the carelessness department.* {sarcastically said}

The French expression "*n'avoir rien à envier à quelqu'un*" has the literal meaning of "*(when it comes to something, someone) **has nothing to feel envious about** (towards someone else)*", and figuratively refers to someone's good quality that is "***every bit as good as*** someone else's".

In real-life usage, however, the expression is often used  jokingly and sarcastically to point out someone's bad quality that is "***every bit as bad as*** someone else's", as shown in the example above.

- "*N'avoir rien à envier à" : avoir des avantages au moins égaux à ceux de quelqu'un, être dans une situation aussi favorable, et, **ironiquement**, être dans une situation aussi **désavantageuse** que quelqu'un.*

I'm not sure if "**не уступать ни в чем**", for instance, covers the ironic aspect of this French expression. How do Russian speakers idiomatically express this idea in conversation?

Comment: Is it "Нечему завидовать"?

Comment: No, he's talking specifically about ironic usage, not the original meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Она сама ничем не лучше / недалеко ушла / Ей нечем хвастать
>
> Так что по части нелепых замечаний она сама ничем не лучше / недалеко ушла / ей нечем хвастать

Answer (score 2):

"`Он(а) сам(а) кому/кого хочешь...`" followed by some action. For example "`Да ты за неё не волнуйся, она сама кого хочешь так пошлёт, что мало не покажется.`"

Answer (score 2):

А close analogue is:  "она в этом кому хочешь даст фору".

Answer (score 1):

> Насчёт оговорок, уж чья бы корова мычала

This is a part of a well-known saying (*поговорка*): *чья бы корова мычала, а твоя бы молчала*.

Its literal meaning is "someone's cow could give a moo (on this matter), but yours would have better kept mum".

This is sarcastic, but not exactly the way the original sentence is.

> Насчёт оговорок она сама кому хочешь сто очков вперёд даст

This means "when it comes to the slips of the tongue, she is a cut above anyone" (literally, "can give a hundred points' handicap to anyone").

This is sarcastic in the same way the original saying is (the phrase can be used without irony), but this one assumes superiority, not being on par.

Answer (score 1):

> По острословию она такая мастерица,
>
> Что никто с ней в этом даже не сравнится.
>
> Любому в этом деле фору она даст
>
> И пальму первенства при этом не отдаст.

My language so abounds in idioms expressing your idea that it took me just a couple of minutes to write this small poem.

Each line there corresponds to a separate idiom, so I hope you'll find something to your liking.

Ah, I almost forgot a little nuance: If, for whatever reason, you want to only say that she  is *not inferior* to anyone, avoiding saying that she is *superior* to anyone, then here you go:

> В этом ее никто за пояс не заткнет.

Answer (score 0):

> Elle n'a rien à envier à personne.(В этом)Она никому не уступит.

Ваш перевод правильный. Эта идиома может употребляться для выражения сарказма.
То, что вы назвали slip of the tongue, на самом деле немножко не то. Тут имелось в виду,  что она остра на язык — еще одно хорошее выражение — и в этом никому не уступит (she is second to none). Ты ей слово — она тебе десять. Разговорное «любого за пояс заткнет» и другие, которые назвали раньше.

Comment: I have an impression that OP is French (not 100% sure though). I would invite him to elaborate on the meaning/usage of "'écart de langage" as it seems to be fairly broad in French...

Comment: I think he is Japanese, but does it matter? He speaks several languages well. The point is "оговариваться" can have different interpretations which is misleading.

Comment: Ну да, догадался заглянуть в профиль наконец... Мой французский оставляет желать, но примеры в интернете намекают на диапазон от невинных оговорок/"ляпов" до "остра на язык"/"за словом в карман не полезет", что, конечно, очень разные вещи. Поэтому хотелось уточнить.

Comment: @tum_ The "écart de langage" is about inappropriate, out-of-place remarks (intentional or otherwise, but mostly about one's words uintentionally coming out all wrong) which you might often hear in an official interview with Trump.